# How to Export modified dataset from pytorch dataloader after augmentations

Tags: deep-learning, object-detection, yolov5, pytorch-dataloader, albumentations

Is there any easy solution for exporting/genarating a custom dataset after applying some transforms i.e., *[Bounding Box Augmentation](https://albumentations.ai/docs/getting_started/bounding_boxes_augmentation/)*?

To elaborate, my goal is to

- import my original dataset(drone images containing small objects) which is in coco format,
- crop the objects from the original image with 20-50% background and the object with a random shift from the cropped image's centres
- decompose the original bounding box annotations and distribute them to the cropped images with scaled and transformed co-ordinates
- export/save to disk the cropped images as a new dataset with annotations ie., in yolov5 or coco format

Example:
`Originalimage.jpg`
[Originalimage.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P0xu.jpg)
and the annotations are(for example in yolo format):
`Originalimage.txt`

```
0 0.3343 0.6527 0.0061 0.0062
0 0.2631 0.6390 0.0058 0.0042
1 0.2790 0.6580 0.0377 0.0125
1 0.1930 0.6303 0.0380 0.0172
1 0.3380 0.5542 0.0372 0.0174
0 0.3702 0.5525 0.0102 0.0086
0 0.3908 0.5963 0.0063 0.0057
0 0.3885 0.5603 0.0061 0.0048
0 0.2083 0.6379 0.0047 0.0038
1 0.3411 0.5700 0.0391 0.0125
```

`Originalimage_crop1.jpg`

[Originalimage_crop1.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQnUE.jpg)

transform original bbox(line 4): `1 0.1930 0.6303 0.0380 0.0172` to augmented bbox: `1 xnew ynew hnew wnew` and save to `Originalimage_crop1.txt`

`Originalimage_crop2.jpg`

[Originalimage_crop2.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1JBQ.jpg)

transform original bbox(line 10): `1 0.3411 0.5700 0.0391 0.0125` to augmented bbox: `1 xnew ynew hnew wnew` and save to `Originalimage_crop2.txt`

and so on...

So far i have only found [roboflow.ai](https://roboflow.ai) to do it in data preprocessing step when tiling an image into nxn grids, it also genarates new annotations to address new object locations in the cropped images. but this tiling/griding is not object aware, so often cuts the objects and genarate a lot of empty/background(without any objects) images.